# Codeigniter 3.0.3 sessions are not persistent

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am having very weird problem, The sessions in Codeigniter 3.0.3 are not saved for next request. Each time when a request is done, it creates a new session record and doesn't use it next time.

The weird part of it is, it **does work** on **HTTPS** version of website, but not **HTTP**.

*The scenario:* On the login page of my website, I do an AJAX call (on this call I set some session variables and flashdatas). Once I get success message, I reload page to the profile page.

This whole process don't work when I use HTTP, but HTTPS.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT v1:** Addition, even **CSRF** doesn't work over HTTP. I disable it to test the system.

**EDIT v2:** Code requested by @DFriend

**config.php**

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'jupiter';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = "hkr_sessions"; 
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '.jupiter.rjv.me';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = TRUE; // PS: tried FALSE version as well, but no change. 
$config['cookie_httponly'] = FALSE;
```

**User.php** controller

```
public function login_required() {
  if (!$this->logged_in()) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata("login_error", "You have to be logged in to see this page.");
    $this->session->set_userdata('redirect_back', $this->agent->referrer());
    redirectt('/login');
  }
}
```

**routes.php**

```
$route['login/required'] = 'user/login_required';
```

A simple method like this, when I browse to `http://domain.ltd/login/required` it redirects to `http://domain.ltd/login` with printing message like *"You have to be logged in to see this page."*. Once the user logins, it redirects user back to the page previously he/she was.

In my case it does redirect to `/login` page, but doesn't print out flashdata message.

Here is **MY_Controller.php**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
  protected $logged_in = NULL;
  protected $is_ajax   = NULL;
  protected $user_id   = NULL;

  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    log_message("DEBUG", "session variables: " . print_r($this->session->all_userdata(), true));

    $this->logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $this->is_ajax = $this->input->is_ajax_request();
    $this->user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
  }
}
```

As you see, I print out session variables on each request.

Here is the output of the sessions over HTTP request:

```
DEBUG - 2016-01-03 07:17:27 --> session variables: Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1451805447
)
```

Here is the output of the sessions over HTTPS request:

```
DEBUG - 2016-01-03 07:19:44 --> session variables: Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1451805564
    [redirect_back] => https://jupiter.rjv.me/book/1497-sefiller-viktor-mari-huqo
)
```

I haven't changed any code, just tried on both requests, HTTP and HTTPS. The session outputs are different. One doesn't save, the other does. I hope this would help you to identify the problem.

Comment: Sessions are sensitive to the protocol (http, https) in use when the session is started. A session set for `http://example.com` is not the same session for `https://example.com` Make sure you are not changing protocols somewhere.

Comment: @DFriend no, I try them differently. I followed up many suggestions & fixes, but no luck. just doesn't work for http and can't figure out why, spent my whole night on this.

Comment: Without code to examine it is impossible to offer more help.

Comment: @DFriend please check out the question EDIT v2. Added some codes, let me know if you need anything else. Thanks!

Comment: Is the hkr_sessions table setup as specified [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver) with a primary key on the 'ip_address' field? This is required when when `sess_match_ip = TRUE`. Have you tried `sess_match_ip = FALSE` to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: @DFriend yeah.It used to write sessions to a directory, I changed it to database to see if it would help or not. Also, just tried `sess_match_ip = FALSE`, nothing has changed.

Comment: Where does `session` library get loaded? `User` controller extends `MY_Controller`?  Is there any AJAX involved? Have you tried setting a cookie prefix?

Comment: @DFriend `session` is autoloaded and yeah, User extends MY_Controller. In this situation no AJAX is involved and I also tried cookie prefix, but no luck. Weird thing is, I have this website running on live server which just works fine with Codeigniter 3.0.1. I just upgraded framework to 3.0.3, that ended up with this issue.

Comment: @DFriend Found the problem and fixed. See the answer below in case you're interested. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually modifying headers on my `.htaccess` file and one rule was causing the issue. See the commented line - that line was the issue.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    Header set X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block"
    Header unset Server
    Header set X-Content-Security-Policy "allow 'self';"
    # Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
</IfModule>
```