# Session in CodeIgniter - did not work accordingly

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm working on session in codeigniter now and I'm not sure where it goes wrong. 
I only manage to read session for the 1st page. When I browse to other page, the session gone. 
The following are the var_dump for dashboard.

```
array(2) {
["__ci_last_regenerate"]=>
int(1487063353)
["logged_in"]=>
array(2) {
["userName"]=>
string(5) "julie"
["userRole"]=>
string(1) "1"
}}
```

and the following are var_dump for the second page and when i go back to dashboard

```
array(1) {
["__ci_last_regenerate"]=>
int(1487063602)
}
```

The following are my codes. Appreciate if you can help me point out the problem and solutions. Thanks in advance.

config/config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 1800; // 30 minutes
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH .'/sessions/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

libraries/SimpleLoginSecure.php

```
function login($user_name,$user_pass)
{
   $this->CI =& get_instance();

   // verification code goes here

   //set session data
   $user_data = $query->row_array();
   $dataSession['userName'] = $user_data['userName'];
   $dataSession['userRole'] = $user_data['userRole'];
   $this->CI->session->set_userdata('logged_in',$dataSession);
   return TRUE;
}
```

controller/Login.php

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index() {
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-red">', '</p>');       
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userName', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userPass', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
        $this->load->view('index');
    }       
}

function verify_user()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('SimpleLoginSecure');

    $hasher = new PasswordHash(8, false);
    $userpass = $this->input->post('inputPassword');
    $username = $this->input->post('inputName');

    $results = $this->simpleloginsecure->login($username,$userpass);
    if($results != FALSE) {
      $SESS_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
      $data['SESS_username'] = $SESS_data['userName'];
      $data['SESS_userrole'] = $SESS_data['userRole'];

      var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());
      $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
  }
  else {
     $attempt = $this->simpleloginsecure->updatePassAttempt($userName);         
     if ($attempt != FALSE) {
        echo '<script>alert("Invalid Username or password"); window.history.back();</script>';
     }      
   }      
}

function logout() {
    $this->load->library('SimpleLoginSecure');

    // Logout
    $this->simpleloginsecure->logout();
    echo '<script>alert("Successfully Logout"); </script>';
    redirect(base_url());
}
```

Comment: can you please your all code for controller

Comment: You means your session values lost on second page?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz yes.. the value gone.. i dont know whats wrong.. and i only put sess_destroy during logout.. even when i go back to dashboard.. no session data captured.

Comment: @NavjotSingh .. sure.. i'll update my posting.. one moment

Comment: On successful login you are setting some value in SESSION, it is available on dashboard page, but note on another page. This is th problem you are facing ?

Comment: you can set data to session simply like this in Codeigniter
In the start of every controller constructor like this.

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
   $this->load->library('session');
}

Comment: @MayankPandeyz correct.. no session value on other page and when i go back to dashboard.. the session gone as well.. the session value only show during the first time display dashboard..

Comment: @NavjotSingh I already load session in autoload.php.. should i put again in all page? No need right?

Comment: In autoload.php is enough

Comment: Did you get something?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz get what? I don't see any errors tho..  and my var_dump only display **array(1) { ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=> int(1487065198) }**

Comment: OK, give me 2 minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135666/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-julie).

Comment: Note: Your name of your library should be **libraries/Simpleloginsecure.php** same with class first letter only upper case. Then `$this->load->library('simpleloginsecure')`; https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: @wolfgang1983 yes.. it is the same.. typo in my posting..

Comment: Hi Julie , plz do not use login function in libraries, you create a same function in helper , and second point your logout function wrong

Comment: @Manishsharma .. I'm using the SimpleLoginSecure library to do password hashing as it is much more easier than developing myself.. and I believe.. for CI.. most developer are using library to do password hashing.. **correct me if im wrong and do let me know which way is better to do password hashing in CI**.. and as for logout function.. I'll look into it.. thank you..

Comment: @Julie : your login function not working about password hashing,,,password hashing different concept.so my recommendation please make it simple demo without your libaray .

Comment: What version of CI are you using? [CI 2 sessions lib was not reliable.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34338027/3585500)

Comment: @ourmandave im using latest version 3.1.3

Comment: @Manishsharma my password hashing with SimpleLoginSecure works correctly.. or at least works as expected.. I dont think it was the cause because I got the session value when open the dashboard.. its just that the value seems destroyed @ reset at the following page..

Comment: @Julie Could it be the obscure [.htaccess modifying headers problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34662283/3585500)

Comment: Also see this answer for common problems persisting a session.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655355/getting-a-checkbox-array-value-from-post

Comment: @ourmandave .. thanks for the article.. i'll go thru it..and i'll check the .htaccess as well.. I've been stuck for days on this issue.. doing other modules to clear my mind.. maybe there's something i missed out.. I just didnt find it yet.. _sigh_

Comment: @Julie : As you wish go ahead

Comment: @Manishsharma I'm not sure whats wrong.. I didnt change my code.. so what I did is.. at dashboard.. when i still have the session value.. i refresh my page manually (press ctrl+R).. after that i navigate to other page and to my surprise.. the session value are there..until I logout... why is that happen?.. why I need to refresh?.. and how to automatically refresh my page after assign the session?..  I'm a bit confuse..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are actually loading the session library, the safest bet if its something that's going to be used 95-100% of the time stick it in autoload.

`application/config/autoload.php` in the libraries array add 'session', this will ensure on initailisation it will always be loaded. Its around line 60:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

The most common issue for this kind of thing occurring is not having the library loaded when you need it.

I would also suggest using a full controller and model for account management instead of libraries or helpers, makes life much easier for you as its within the standard CI scope.

Comment: I did put session in autoload..  and as for account management .. to verify user.. i use SimpleLoginSecure as I'm using the library to do password hashing..